# Adapter to connect old laptops into thunderbolt display/usb

Tags: usb, hdmi, thunderbolt, adapter

Normally, searching for Thunderbolt adapters, we get things doing

- A thunderbolt on input.
- An USB and HDMI output.

Thus, we can connect a thunderbolt laptop to a HDMI monitor and USB keyboard.

**What I want, that is the exact opposite.**

I have an old laptop without a Thunderbolt connector. I want to connect it into a Thunderbolt cable. So I need a thing where

- I can plug in the HDMI and USB in some adapter
- a thunderbolt cable comes out where the other side thinks, it is a  thunderbolt laptop.

On this way, a normal and such an "inverse thunderbolt adapter" could work like a remote console for old laptops.

Does such a thing exist? Webshops and search engines show up always only the "forward" variant, unfortunately.

P.s. normally, thunderbolt gives also power. That is a no-issue in my case (I can live with it if it can not happen).

Comment: What is the make and model number of the display?

Comment: @Romen HDMI is the connector. The numbers are attached to the back of my monitor, at the moment it is not easy for me to see them. May I ask you, how could it be important?

Comment: It's important because you're asking how to attach an old laptop to the display. We need more information to answer this question and the model number carries a lot of information.

Comment: @Romen Not that is the question. The question is, how to connect the old laptop to the thunderbolt.

Comment: @Romen Btw, it is an usual HDMI monitor. Used normally over a thunderbolt adapter. Except that some of my "old" laptops have no thunderbolt connector. No, "just connect it directly to the HDMI" is NAA (not-an-answer, valid delete reason on the SE).

Comment: I see, if you don't mind me asking though; Why is "just connect it directly to the HDMI" not an answer for you? Is there something about thunderbolt that makes this monitor better? I still think knowing the model number of the monitor (and maybe the laptop you're trying to connect to it) are helpful information to answer the question too. Somebody might be able to tell you about a brand-specific adapter that does what you want.

Comment: I think there is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) going on here where you're asking for an adapter (question Y) to solve some other problem (X). What is that other problem? Do you actually want a "remote console" for an old laptop?

Comment: I am prepared to write an answer for the question as it is written now. That kind of adapter doesn't exist. But if you asked for something more general that would accomplish the same end result that you're looking for then my answer could be more helpful.

Comment: @Romen Ok, but you know, it is an ordinary HDMI monitor and my laptop has an ordinary HDMI output. There is nothing special with it, it could just simply be connected by a HDMI cable. But not this is what I want to.

Comment: @Romen I am sorry but the "XY problem" does not exist in my opinion. What does exist, that is that the community wants to answer a different question, and not the asked one. So they enforce their will to the OP to alter his question for their taste. If the OP resists, the question will be downvoted/closed/deleted. I explained it manywhere on your refered link and also on other places, unfortunately all of them were deleted (in my opinion, as power misuse and intolerance for minority opinions).

Comment: @Romen However, now the simple fact is that the question what you want to likely answer, that has some HDMI cable or KVM extender based solution, and not this one. This is very unfortunate, but I think if a question has no solution, I think the best is to give an answer that it does not exist. Furthermore, to explain, if it could exist or it has some technological limitation.

Comment: I simply want to get to the root of the issue and provide an answer that can actually help you. I used to work in a an electronics store selling video cables and adapters and learned that you should always qualify the customer's issues, they often ask for an adapter that doesn't exist to connect two things that have another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter you want does not exist.

Thunderbolt is not bidirectional, there is a host side and a client side in its design.
In the normal "forward" adapters the host is the computer, and the computer has a chipset inside that essentially converts the Thunderbolt device into a PCI express device. It is closely integrated with the CPU or southbridge on the motherboard. Thunderbolt cannot even be added to PCs that don't have it (at the time of answering, USB 4.0 might change that).

In that "reverse" adapter you proposed, the adapter would have to be the thunderbolt host because the laptop is not. That would require a rather high performance embedded CPU and OS to allow the thunderbolt end to function at all. This is cost prohibiting for a simple video adapter and I expect that is the reason why nobody has made one as a product you can buy.

Comment: I believe it would not be so hard to create one. No CPU and OS would be needed, only an embedded chip.

Comment: Thunderbolt is essentially a PCIe bus. You will need a "chip" that has a PCI express host controller, which is already narrowing the scope to an ARM or x86 CPU. CPUs like that necessarily have some kind of OS even if it's an embedded linux OS that does one job. You could actually make one though, I imagine a desktop PC with thunderbolt and an HDMI capture card could be set up to do the job of that adapter. Unfortunately that's more like a development platform than an actual useful product.